# N Balls in two urns

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, balls-in-bins

Let A and B tow urns containing both N balls numbered from $1$ to $N$.

- 1) We assume to extract casually one ball from A and one ball from B. What is the probability that they have the same number?

$\rightarrow \mathbb{P}($same number at the first extraction$)=\frac{1}{N^2}$

- 2) We assume to remove from urns the balls extracted only if these balls are equal, and to repeat a second time the extraction. What is the probability to obtain two equal numbers at the second extraction?
- 3) Knowing that at the second extraction we have obtained tow equal numbers, waht is the probability that even at the first extraction were obtained two equal numbers?

---

I have difficulty to solve the second point, because for the third point just apply Bayes. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You made an error already in point 1).

Comment: @user Thanks. Could you explain me where I wrong?

Comment: The correct answer to 1) is $1/N$. Try to elaborate why (it is very simple).

Comment: I think where you wrote "casually" you mean "independently uniformly randomly"?

Comment: @joriki I don't know. I only copied the text.

Comment: If you copy text, you should provide the source.